# construct key value pair array by providing list of values(string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I would be passing list of countries as environment variables as shown below

```
tag = 'us,gb,au,de'
```

I would like to dynamically construct key value array as shown below.

```
var placeList =
           [{place: 'us'},
            {place: 'gb'},
            {place: 'au'},
            {place: 'de'}];
```

I tried using .forEach, but was not sure how to construct one, any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split the string on the comma then convert each string you receive in to an object

```
var placeList = tag.split(',').map(str => ({place: str}))
```